# Removing event listeners with anonymous function calls in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures, dom-events

I'm trying to remove an event listener for created span elements where the function called is within a closure. I've tried various methods and none seem to work.

```
var MyClass = function () {}

MyClass.prototype.addSpan = function (el) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = "Text here";
    el.appendChild(span);
    span.addEventListener('click', (function (obj) { 
        return function () { 
            obj.removeSpan(); 
        }
    })(this), false);
}

MyClass.prototype.removeSpan = function () {
    alert('removing span');
    this.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee, false);
    // .... remove span .... 
}

myclass = new MyClass();

myclass.addSpan(document.getElementById('box'));
```

I've also used

```
this.removeEventListener('click', (function (obj) { 
    return function () { 
        obj.removeSpan(); 
    }
})(this), false);
```

in place of `this.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee, false);` but had no luck.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Simplify the unnecessary closure: (function (obj) { return function () { obj.removeSpan(); })(this)
-> function( obj ) { obj.removeSpan(); }

Comment: In your example the obj will refer to the event rather than the class.

Comment: Why are you trying to call removeSpan from removeEventLister? Your removeEventListener calls removeSpan. It's infinite recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var MyClass = function () {}
MyClass.prototype.listener=null;
MyClass.prototype.addSpan = function (el) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = "Text here";
    el.appendChild(span);
    span.addEventListener('click', (function (obj) { 
        return obj.listener = function () { 
            obj.removeSpan(this); // here 'this' refers to 'span'
        }
    })(this), false);
}

MyClass.prototype.removeSpan = function (el) {
    alert('removing span');
    el.removeEventListener('click', this.listener, false);
    // .... remove span .... 
}

myclass = new MyClass();
myclass.addSpan(document.getElementById('box'));
```

Without a reference of the listener you can't remove it, so I've also added a property (listener) to the MyClass' prototype and then returned the reference as `return obj.listener` and also you need to pass the object as I've passed it `obj.removeSpan(this);` and in the `removeSpan` I've received with `el` so I could've done `el.removeEventListener`, hope it helps.

You can also do this

```
var MyClass = function () {this.listener=null;}
```

instead of

```
MyClass.prototype.listener=null;
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mzSuF/).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your event handler to this.

```
span.addEventListener('click', (function (obj) { 

        span.onclick = null;

        return function () { 
            obj.removeSpan(); 
        }
    })(this), false);
```

Comment: I tried putting that in place of the original but no luck unfortunately :(